# PHP searching multiple rows in database

Tags: php, search, mysqli

I am wanting to search more than column from one database with PHP and MySQL. Currently I have this working.

This is my form:

```
  <form action="products.php" method="POST">
  Search: <input type="text" name="search" />
  <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
  </form>
```

and here is my current working query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `GraphicsCards` WHERE `Brand` LIKE '%". $search . "%'";
$run = mysqli_query ($connection, $query);
```

As you can see my query is searching my database to see if the user search entered matches anything in the column "Brand".

I have other columns such as "Model" "Price" etc etc, and would like to be able to search those as well as just "Brand". Is it possible to do this is one query?

In addition I have already tried ' AND ' and ' OR ' and also ' || ' but they do not work.

Comment: Why doesn't OR work?

Comment: I don't know when I add OR the query no longer displays data :/

Comment: Make sure `$search` is escaped correctly if it comes from user input, otherwise you'll have a SQL injection vulnerability. It is best to switch to parameterised queries if you can, for this reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`OR` will work, you just have to do it correctly.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `GraphicsCards`
    WHERE `Brand` LIKE '%". $search . "%'
        OR `Model` LIKE '%" . $search . "%'
        OR `Price` LIKE '%" . $search . "%'";
```

And just FYI, `Brand`, `Model`, and `Price` are columns, not rows.

Comment: Patrick you wonderful guy!! It works! Thank you and God Bless :)

Comment: @AbdushSamadMiah You're welcome. If you could just mark the answer as accepted since it solved your problem, that would be appreciated.

Comment: lool and cheers for the FYI above, I shall remember for future reference :)

Comment: Just waiting for it to allow me and will do as soon as it does. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You should try:

```
$query = "
    SELECT * FROM `GraphicsCards`
    WHERE
        `Brand` LIKE '%". $search . "% OR `Model` LIKE %'" . $search . "%";
$run = mysqli_query ($connection, $query);
```

Let me know how it works.

Comment: Hi Asaf thanks for the response Patrick's answer above resolved my issue I appreciate your response. Cheers