# how to perform search in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to perform a search from the database using php in which when i enter name arun it should search for name arun and display the result with name arun and when i enter name and email it should search for name and email and should display single result since the email is unique field i have written the following code but it is not working can someone help me?
Please add a comment if any one gives Downvote and Why?

```
<?php

if (isset($_SESSION['message11'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['message11'];
    unset($_SESSION['message11']);
}
?>

<?php

include('connection.php');
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$qualification = $_POST['qualify'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM form WHERE Name ='$name' OR EmailAddress = '$email' OR Qualification = '$qualification' ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if (!empty($_POST)) {
    if ($result->num_rows === 0) {
        echo '<p style="margin-left:340px">no records</p>';
    }
}



while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $_SESSION["snum"] = $row['sno'];
    $_SESSION["nam"] = $row['Name'];
    $_SESSION["quali"] = $row['Qualification'];
    $_SESSION["emai"] = $row['EmailAddress'];

    echo '<br>';
    echo '<form name="friend" action="received.php" method="post">';
    echo '<input style="margin-left:340px;padding-bottom:10px" type="checkbox" value="' . $row['sno'] . '" name="friend[]">&nbsp;user Details</input>';
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<div class="container" style="border-style:solid; border-width:medium;width: 550px;">';
    echo '<br>';
    echo 'Name: ' . $row['Name'];
    echo '<br /> EmailAddress: ' . $row['EmailAddress'];
    echo '<br /> Qualification: ' . $row['Qualification'];
    echo '<br /> DOB: ' . $row['DOB'];
    echo '<br/>';
    echo '<br/>';

    echo '<br/>';
    echo '<br/>';

    echo '</div>';
    echo '<br/>';
}

if (!empty($_POST)) {
    echo '<button style="margin-left:340px" type=""submit">invite</button>';
}
echo '</form>';
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: **it is not working** can you explain which part is not working??

Comment: What error do you encounter?

Comment: May this Solutions is help You. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27850383/php-searching-multiple-rows-in-database

Comment: Just try to print the $sql you will come to know. You have made a small mistake you can do it by your self. No need to take help dude.

Comment: in which part you want to perform search? write your query with like operator eg: SELECT * FROM form WHERE Name LIKE '%$name%' for more refrence http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Comment: above code is working but when i search it will display result from the database when i enter the name,emailaddress and qualifiacation

Comment: So reading your comment what is exactly the problem will it only display 1 row. Does it give an error. Doesn't it return any rows. In your question you say and I quote "I have written the following code but it is not working can someone help me?". But then in the comment on the question you say and I quote again "above code is working but when I search it will display result from the database when I enter the name,emailaddress and qualifiacation" so I have a hard time figuring out what the problem is you are facing. Please point out what the exact problem is.

Comment: when i enter the name as arun it should display the all the name which matches arun and when i enter the email address it should match with the name and email and should display the result since the email field is unique when i enter the name and email address it should display a single value

Comment: also as @NietTheDarkAbsol mentions in the awnser Pupil provided you are not using parametrised queries your code is open to SQL-Injections and unless you want some 12y/o that found a DROP TABLE query on the internet and thinks he is funny to ruin your website use prepared statements

Comment: im just a beginner and a learner i dnt know  about such things  thats y im asking questions here  i will correct it in future dnt put down vote im not able ask questions if i cant able to ask questions i cant learn about such things i know i have mistake in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding `OR` condition to three fields even if they are not entered by the user.

Use conditions so that sql should search only entered fields.

Use `array()`

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM form WHERE ";
$conditions = array();
if (! empty($name)) {
  $conditions[] = "Name ='$name'";
}
if (! empty($email)) {
  $conditions[] = "EmailAddress ='$email'";
}
if (! empty($qualification)) {
  $conditions[] = "Qualification ='$qualification'";
}
$sql .= ! empty($conditions) ? implode(' OR ', $conditions) : '1';
$result=$conn->query($sql);
```

Comment: I want to upvote for providing the correct method - even going so far as to check that any conditions were entered at all - but you did not advise the user to use parametrised queries (eg. PDO) instead of blindly injecting values from the user.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol you are completely right there is no excuse not to use prepared statements nowadays

Answer (score -1):

Try this **LIKE** will be effective for searching stuffs.

Simple and best practice.

```
SELECT * FROM form WHERE Name LIKE '%".$name."%' OR EmailAddress LIKE '%".$email."%' OR Qualification LIKE '%".$qualification."%'
```

Comment: With no `_` or `%`, `LIKE` is equivalent to `=`. Not to mention, you are still injecting values into the query and claiming "best practice".